# Python in Visual Studio (PTVS): Debug not working but Run works

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I installed PTVS 2.1 on MS Visual Studio 2013 and then created a simple python project showing 'Hello World'.
When I Start Without Debugging I see the shell and 'Hello World' message, everything is fine. But when I try Start Debug, nothing happens, no errors are reported, no shell comes up, no breakpoints get reached, nothing!

Any suggestion?

**My platform and packages:**

Win 8.1 64bit 
VS 2013 Ultimate
Python 2.7.9 64bit
PTVS 2.1 64bit

---

**UPDATE**:

I just found that in Visual Studio 2010, this problem does not exists.

Comment: Please file a bug in the bug tracker: https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/basic/