# Python script does not find file when run interactively in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio to run a single python file. This is not a project, just a single file. As usual everything works fine, but when i try utilize another file it will not be found.

[image]

I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.xlsx'`

I run python files using "`Execute in Python Interactive button`"

[image]

Everything works great when I run Start without debugging.

[image]

It executes as expected

[image]

Comment: Are you actually in a project in Visual Studio (even if this very file is not)? That could mean that the working directory is the root of the project and not your directory `matplotlib` where the script and excel file is. (And therefore is looking for the file in the wrong directory)

Comment: Everything works great when I run Start without debugging.

Comment: Which version of `Visual Studio` are you running? This seems to be a more visual-studio related problem than a python trying to find a file one. For comparison https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582683/python-in-visual-studio-ptvs-debug-not-working-but-run-works